# How to save a newly created view as the default view?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, modern-experience

Strange, strange. I have created a new view but can find anywhere the option to set my view as default view. There use to be an option but it is gone.

Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 1):

From SharePoint modern experience list view, after making required changes:

1. Click on **Switch view options** dropdown at the top right corner.
2. Select **Set current view as default**.

[image]

---

**Solution 2** - From classic view settings:

1. Click on **Switch view options** dropdown at the top right corner.
2. Select **Edit current view**.
3. Check **Make this the default view** checkbox
4. Click **OK**

[image]

---

**Update from comments**:

You can only make the public view as the default view. If your view is *private view*, this will not work.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. But i knew all that. But still doesn't have the options to set my view als default. The only options I have are: make new view, save view as, edit current view and style current view. But not "Set current view als default" !.

Comment: Is this the **Private view**? You can only make the **public view** as the default view. Also, what permissions you have at list level?

Comment: It was indeed a private view. thank your for your solution. Gr. p